# Synonym Support for Azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have gone through the discussions on both these threads

[Does Azure Search handle synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180405/does-azure-search-handle-synonyms)
[Misspelling & synonym support for Azure Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306557/misspelling-synonym-support-for-azure-search)

My question is whether full synonym support has been added or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are actively working to add great support for synonyms to Azure Search. Details to be announced soon. Right now we have limited support though [SynonymTokenFilters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt605304.aspx).

Comment: As Yahnoosh mentioned, we're working on first-class support for synonyms. If you'd like to help us shape this feature and try it out as a early adopter, please email nateko at the usual Microsoft domain.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we faced the same barrier. 
As the synonyms in Azure search are only a mapping. This was our workaround to make it better:

1. Based on our documents we trained a synonym map (using gensim).
2. We deployed that model in the cloud using Azure Machine learning service.
3. In our UI we send a call to the Azure ml model with our given in words. Whereafter we take the words given by our own model. We give in these words to the search engine.

I hope this workflow can give you some ideas to improve your project.